# Entity manager throwing "ResultSet is from update. No data" even when the csv is generated

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jdbc

I am trying to run a native sql query using java.persistence.Query interface.

Native query is like this :

```
SELECT '"id"', '"numerical_values"', '"string_values"'
UNION ALL
SELECT id, numerical_values, CONCAT('"', REPLACE(string_values, '"', '""'), '"')
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/values.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM values_table;

Query qry = dataManager.createNativeQuery(MY_QUERY));
qry.getResultList();
```

When I run the above code then my csv gets generated correctly but the code breaks with the following exception.

```
java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
```

There are only getResultList(), getSingleResult() and executeUpdate() methods available on my dataManager object. Kindly suggest what should I do to resolve this. Should I write JDBC code for this?

I am using javax.persistence.EntityManager.

Comment: Your query doesn't produce a result set, it populates a CSV file, so using `getResultList` is wrong, use `executeUpdate`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Already tried this but no success as its a select statement. Getting   java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue executeUpdate() for SELECTs

Comment: Interesting conundrum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unwrap the EntityManager into JDBC and accomplish this with relative ease:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap( Session.class );
session.doWork(new Work() {         
    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
        try {
            pStmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            pStmt.execute();
        } finally {
            if (pStmt != null) {
                pStmt.close();
            }                       
        }

    }
});
```